# Uploading files with PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having trouble with setting up the file upload to my php script.

Within the upload itself, I have it directed towards the path I want, but I'm not sure if I have the rest of the script syntactically right.

**EDIT:** I have resolved my situation with the file not properly uploading. I have edited the blocks of code to what I have currently working. If needed, please refer to the pre-edited version to see changes :).

Cheers.

```
$tardir= "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploaddir/$targetname";
$uploadOk=1;

if(isset($_FILES["uploadFile"])){
    $tardir= $tardir . "/" . basename($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $tardir)){ 
        echo "The file: ". basename($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

The `$targetname`is set to whatever the user inputs in the field. In this case, I have it as their email.

```
$targetname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
```

This is what the `<html>` for the file upload looks like:

```
<form action= "userlogin.php" method= "post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
        <p><strong>Please choose a file to upload: <input type="file" name="uploadFile"><br></p>
           <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
```

Comment: In the error, which variable is throwing an undefined index error?

Comment: uploadFile is throwing the error twice. @ColinSchoen

Comment: Careful... you're letting people upload whatever they want to your server, and you're keeping it in the doc root.  Someone can upload malicious scripts and execute them easily.

Comment: It's just for a lab exercise in our class. It isn't a live server. Just for my practical use and testing :) @Brad

Comment: Is `file_uploads = On` in your php.ini?

Comment: You bet. First thing I checked. @ColinSchoen

Comment: Enable error reporting in your script (or if you're working on a development server in php.ini)

Comment: Even with error reporting in my script, the file still isn't being uploaded to the designated path. It returns me to the .html file... @Gervs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to guess all your code, as it seems you only have a snippet here, but I'm gonna take a wild guess. If target name comes from a text input like you say and you have it set to e-mail, are you leaving off a slash here?

```
$tardir= "C:/xampp/htdocs/uploaddir/$targetname";
```

This would be like:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/uploaddir/me@gmail.com
```

This runs:

```
$tardir= $tardir . basename($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
```

then:

```
 C:/xampp/htdocs/uploaddir/me@gmail.comfilename
```

shouldn't it be:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/uploaddir/me@gmail.com/filename
```

you can also comment out all your code here and var_dump() your file array, and echo out your paths before you try using them to see what data is held in each of your containers. If I get a bug like this I dump everything and echo every string until I find it..